# Getting the number of connect data while skipping the duplicates

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates, grouping

Ok, Im sure Im going to get the minus for this but I sipmly cannot find the solution.
I have table that goes like this:

```
date | name
-------------
1       Peter
2    |   Peter
3    |   Peter
3    |   Peter
4    |   Peter
```

And when I do the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(date) FROM day WHERE name 'Peter'
```

It comes out " 5 " instead of "4"

I tried couple of options and simply cannot get the number of times of the same name is being mentioned in the same Date while skipping duplicates.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please post a more detailed description of your table, ideally the `DESCRIBE yourtable;` - output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, however you misplaced the DISTINCT keyword. The way you placed it MySQL will select distinct Counts rather than distinct dates. Try placing it like so:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT Date) FROM day WHERE name LIKE 'Peter'
```

This way MySQL will look for distinct dates, as intended.

Comment: your first answer and first accept and nice start :) good luck +1

Comment: Fantastic, worked perfectly. Thats exactly what I wanted. Thank you!